# Add HTML tag to strings in PHP array using str_ireplace

Tags: php, html, arrays, replace, str-replace

I want to mark (highlight) the keywords a user has input as search parameters.
I've tried the following PHP code to do this. It adds the  tag effectively but for some reason displays each string as "Array" rather than it's value.

```
$find = array("HELLO","WORLD"); // Case-insensitive
$arr = array("Hello","world","!");
print_r(str_ireplace($find,'<mark>'.$find.'</mark>',$arr));
```

https://i.imgur.com/7vryXlY (demo image, not enough rep to embed)

Comment: change it to this print_r(str_ireplace($find,$replace,$arr)); then it will work

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @ShakeelAhmad! That does work, but I need the html <mark> tag added to the results which that doesn't do.
Edit: I realise I'd left the $replace array in my code, which may have caused confusion, removed it now as it's unneeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only replace an array with an array.  You can either loop:

```
$result = $arr;
foreach($find as $v) {
    $result = str_ireplace($v, "<mark>$v</mark>", $result);
}
```

Or create a replacement array from the `$find` array:

```
$repl = array_map(function($v) { return "<mark>$v</mark>"; }, $find);
$result = str_ireplace($find, $repl, $arr);
```

Or combined:

```
$result = str_ireplace($find, array_map(function($v) { return "<mark>$v</mark>"; }, $find), $arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help, that combined solution is very concise and worked a treat!